# Возможно ли передать свой параметр/параметры в call-back функцию WinApi?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Гуглил этот вопрос, но ответа все таки, так и не смог найти. Вопрос собственно такой:
Вот к примеру есть такой простой код:

```
int Global_counter;
 
static BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND   hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
 
    static_Global_counter++;
 
    return TRUE;
}
 
 
int main()
{
    Global_counter = 0;
 
    BOOL My_bool_EnumWindows =  EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
 
    std::cout << Global_counter << std::endl;
}
```

То есть я вызываю функцию EnumWindows с call-back функцией EnumWindowsProc - для подсчета открытых окон, но так как передать в cal-back функцию возможности нет, пришлось создать глобальную переменную Global_counter и суммировать кол-во сработанных EnumWindowsProc в нее.

И вот все таки вопрос, можно ли как то в EnumWindowsProc  - передать свои параметры по указателю или ссылке ?

Есть у функции EnumWindows - какой то второй параметр lParam, который как бы передается в EnumWindowsProc  - но не понятно, как и возможно ли это использовать для придачи к примеру указателя на char или int.

Comment: Можно использовать lParam, он для этого и предназначен. Он определен как LONG_PTR (см. табличку [Windows Data Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)), т.е. указатель, так что указатели через него можно передавать, просто при передаче и при получении в колбэке кастовать в нужный тип.

Comment: insolor, Спасибо!! Сработало! Но, получается, что за один вызов EnumWindowsProc я могу передать только один параметр ?

Comment: Когда требуется передать больше одного параметра, их следует упаковать в структуру и передать указатель на нее.